# Snowflake: How to filter on a "field name" that contains spaces? It works fine in select statement but not in whereclause filter

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This code works fine:

```
SELECT distinct "Line Status" from TEMP_TS_SUBSCR_ACCT_CUST_INFO;
```

but this code returns error:

```
SELECT * from TEMP_TS_SUBSCR_ACCT_CUST_INFO where "Line Status" = "Active";
```

*SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 66 invalid identifier '"Active"'*

Please advise what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[String literals](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-text.html#string-constants) should be enclosed with `'` or `$$`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TEMP_TS_SUBSCR_ACCT_CUST_INFO 
WHERE "Line Status" = 'Active'; 
-- WHERE "Line Status" = $$Active$$;
```

Double quotes are required for [identifiers](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html) that contain spaces (here column name).